# how to change Linux machine listening port on putty?

Tags: linux, port, putty

I hope you all doing well!
I am working on my Linux machine and My machine listen on port 3868 now I want to change to 3869

Comment: This is not a question for Stack Overflow. Try SuperUser instead.

Comment: which service is using 3868?

Comment: why does that matter?

Comment: Typically DIAMETER uses TCP or SCTP as its transport protocol. Its well-known port is 3868

Comment: And `hp OVSAM MgmtServer Disco` is `3869`.

Comment: David C.Rankin can you please describe little bit

Comment: On your Linux box, just open the file `/etc/services` that lists what typically uses which port. Just look for unused ports in the 7000+ range and you are generally safe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

go to your sshd config file, change port and restart ssh service.

```
vim /etc/ssh/sshd_config
    Port 3869
systemctl restart sshd.service
```